# Why does my Xcode 5 doesn't autocomplete nothing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, autocomplete

I'm starting a project but I have another one very similar as base.

I create my new project with storyboard and CoreData, create a new file of NSObject class, and when I start writing in the .h file:

```
@property (nonanatomic, retain) ns...
```

nsstring or any type of variable doesn't appear... for example, I start writing **ns** and it appears:

- NS_DURING
- NS_ENDHANDLER
- NS_HANDLER
- NS_VALUERETURN
- NS_VOIDRETURN

and the most of code is in black letter, i mean, nothing is coloured as it shoud be normal like purple, blue, etc... the colour that xcode sets... here you can see it:
http://oi61.tinypic.com/359iws6.jpg

P.S: I'm using Xcode 5 Preview 3 and OsX Mavericks. I've never had this problem I think.

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Comment: @cabellicar123 already done and nothing happens. the most strange thing is that if i create a new file and start writing it happens the error i'm asking, but if i drag and drop from the base project i'm using, it works... i don't understand nothing, and I have already created a new project twice...

Comment: Are you sure the class `hello` is imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly   your dot-`m` (the implementation) file is not a member of the target.

When adding a new file to the project on the bottom of the save dialog there is a `Target Membership` window . Did you check that box?

To view the target membership and/or to add an existing file to your target open the implementation file. Then open the File Inspector using <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> or `View`, `Utilities`, `Show File Inspector`.

In the File Inspector window halfway down there is the `Target Membership`. Check the box next to your target.

Syntax highlighting will begin after a short moment, wait for Xcode to finish its indexing.

Comment: omg, it was that! but why is that option disabled by default? what's the sense of having that unchecked? thank you very much ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. No idea why the box is unchecked by default. When adding more files the box will remember the last used target, but first time round it is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this: In XCode open Preferences, click on the Text Editing Tab and make sure "Use Escape key to show completion suggestions" is checked.

Comment: can you specify where I can find it?